# Filter and Unique array of object in javascript with underscore.js based on two property

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my application i have an array like this :

```
var arr=[
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:false},
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:false},
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:true},
 {id:2,name:"ali",deny:false},
 {id:3,name:"reza",deny:true},
 {id:2,name:"ali",deny:true}
];
```

now I want to return unique collection of this array based on `id` of object but if collection have `true` value for `deny` it must return the object that have `deny=true`. for example :

```
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:false},
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:false},
 {id:1,name:"mohammmad",deny:true},
```

it filter with `id=1` but return the object that have `deny=true`.
i also create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fezit/1/edit?js,console) here .

Comment: What if there are matching ID's, but no objects with `deny:true`, only `deny:false`? What I'm really asking is, can we just remove anything that is `deny:false` and filter the rest ?

Comment: so it return `deny:false`

Comment: I don't think unique is going to help you, because the time you applied `uniq` it will filter the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using underscore:

```
_.chain(arr)
  .sortBy(function(d) { return !d.deny })
  .uniq(function(d) { return d.id })
  .value()
```

Sort by `deny` (with true values first), then `uniq` on `id`. Underscore's [implementation of `uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-53) keeps the first matching value for each key. Therefore, if a given `id` had a value with `deny: true`, that value will be kept. If it didn't, it keeps first value with any value of `deny`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitfieldseed/djdd07yj/)